# Must a Django REST Framework app really be a subfolder of the project's root app folder?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm diving through the Django REST framework learning material and something made me doubt.

I noticed that in the [Quickstart page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/), they recommend to create the app as a subfolder of the root app's folder (using the dot at the end of the command *django-admin.py startproject tutorial .*): see this [image of the Quickstart folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMfru.png).

But the [Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) starts by just creating the normal Django folder structure: the app folder is put directly in the project folder (so, not as a subfolder of the root app folder): see this [image of the Tutorial folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B56RY.png).

The Quickstart page defends its way of structuring the folders by stating that it's necessary to avoid name clashes. If this is a best practice or just a necessity to avoid my project from crashing, I just don't understand why the Tutorial doesn't start off with this best practice folder structuring as well.

Can someone clarify if this "best practice" odd folder restructuring (like in the Quickstart page) is then actually really necessary? After having finished learning the Django REST framework, I'm going to set up a real project, and I'd like to know if I can stick to the normal folder structures that I'm used to (as in the Tutorial example), or not.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, All apps must be inside the main project folder.

If you start a Django project with

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

It should have **structure** like this:

```
myproject
   |
   |----myproject
   |      |----__init__.py
   |      |----settings.py
   |      |----urls.py
   |      |----wsgi.py
   |
   |----customapp1
   |      |-----migrations folder
   |      |-----templates folder
   |      |-----static folder
   |      |-----__init__.PY
   |      |-----models.py
   |      |-----views.py
   |      |-----other files
   |
   |----customapp2
   |      |-----migrations folder
   |      |----- all other files and folders
   |
   |----cutomapp3 and etc.......
```

Comment: Hi Astik, I updated my question, it must be that it wasn't formulated clear enough. What I want to know, is whether it's really necessary to have a DRF app as a SUBfolder of the root app in a Django folder, or not, as I think this is strange compared to the folder structuring that is taught in Django's learning material.

Comment: Both `django-project` structure and `django-rest-project` struture is same. There is no change in that. Just try it out it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. It doesn't answer my question yet, however, I'm sorry. I know this folder structure is what Django recommends. The Django REST Framework states though, in its Quickstart (link) page, that the folder structure should be: myproject/myproject/customapp1, instead of myproject/customapp1.
I was wondering if I could keep having my folder structures "the Django way", without problems thrown by the Django REST Framework.

Comment: What problem it throws?? I don't think it should throw the error. Both have same  structure.

Comment: Application is created inside **project directory** and not **app directory**.

Comment: I don't have a problem YET (fortunately). The Quickstart page just mentions "It may look unusual that the application has been created within the project directory. Using the project's namespace avoids name clashes with external module." (from: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) So they suggest you SHOULD adhere with their different folder structuring to avoid problems, and at the same time they ignore this theirselves in the first tutorial page (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). So basically, if I ignore it too in my project, is it safe?

Comment: I dont't think you will face any problem.

Comment: "Application is created inside project directory and not app directory." => I know that's the Django recommendation. The Django REST Framework's Quickstart page just tells to do otherwise. If I do what you say (the Django recommendation), I might risk that my Django REST Framework implementation runs into problems. If I do as the Django REST Framework says, I might run into problems with Django itself. So I'm confused.

Comment: OK, I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: In such a structure, would I be able to import customapp1.models from within customapp2?
Would I be able to do so in any other way?

Comment: @PanosVl, yes you can import another app model in another app.